# Como saber si el Oracle GoldenGate – Processor Perpetual esta en uso en una BD

Tags: linux, api, oracle, ubuntu, plsql

quería recurrir a su sabio conocimiento con un tema y es como saber si el paquete Oracle GoldenGate – Processor Perpetual esta siendo utilizado en una base de datos en un sistema operativo LINUX, ya mediante el comando select * from v$option ORDER BY PARAMETER ASC; veo que la opción Oracle GoldenGate – Processor Perpetual aparece activa en true, muchas gracias por el apoyo eternamente agradecido, soy nuevo en este tema de BD y me visto documentación relacionada pero de verdad que no comprendo muy bien que debo hacer.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.